# Merge two datasets based on fuzzy string matching

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

I want to match a list of addresses to my current database. I used `fuzzy wuzzy` library to match string based on addresses.

Here's what I got

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import pandas as pd

mega_build = pd.read_csv('Address List.csv')
db = pd.read_csv('Database.csv')

mega_bd_address = mega_build['Building Address']
choices = db['Property Address 1']
for address in mega_bd_address:
    top_match = process.extractOne(address, choices)
    alt_match = process.extract(address, choices, limit=3)
    print top_match,alt_match
```

I wanted to return the information such as ID from my database and write to a csv file but not sure how to do it.

An example of the result I'm looking for as below..

```
ID         top_match                alt_match
894R ('108 N State Street', 88) [('108 N State Street', 88), ('6916 N. Lakewood Avenue', 85), ('3100 N. Sheridan Road', 85)]
1234 ('11 S. Green', 95) [('11 S. Green', 95), ('123 S. Green St', 86), ('5555 S. Everett Avenue', 85)]
```

So how do I merge these two datasets based on the fuzzy matching result?